# Setup Debian Server, Symlink from /var/www/dir to another directory

Tags: php, linux, debian

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Request comes in : sub.mydomain.co.uk

I have to DocumentRoot setup as /var/www/common

I make a symbolic link in /var/www/common like "ln -s /home/user/folder/ sub.mydomain.co.uk"

How do I get apache to recognize that as a user directory and follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need but should be enough to start. First of all, www-data user (debian's default for apache) have to have access to /home/user/folder

You can then create new configuration for apache in file `/etc/apache/sites-available/virtuals`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/common/default/
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/common/%0

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you need to activate this config with

```
a2ensite virtuals
service apache2 reload
```

It is probably better to disable default configuration with

```
a2dissite default
service apache2 reload
```

In `/var/www/common/default` should be some default page when non-existent page is requested.

With this config you can simply create directory for any domain you wish to handle on server `/var/www/common` so `http://one.simple.domain.com` will be provided from `/var/www/common/one.simple.domain.com directory`

Also more secure is to set `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` instead of `FollowSymlinks`, see appropriate documentation.

Comment: Hi thanks for this reply, although i get the error - Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration